# Matrix manipulation in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

I have this code:

```
    \documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \matrix[matrix of nodes,
    inner sep=0pt,
    anchor=south west,
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={draw=black!30,
            anchor=center,
            align=center,
            minimum size=1cm,
            outer sep=0pt,
         }
    ]{
       -t & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1-t & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 1-t & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & -1 & 0 & 1-t & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & -t-1 \\
       };
    \end{tikzpicture}  
    \end{document}
```

There is a way in order to:

1. have the nodes of the matrix in mathmode
2. circle some specific node and bar the other on the same column and row like in this picture.

   [image]
3. numerate automatically rows and columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For math nodes, use `matrix of math nodes` instead of `matrix of nodes`, but it appears you need to remove `align=center` for that to work.

If you give a name to the matrix, e.g. `m` as in the code below, you can access the individual nodes with `m-<rownum>-<colnum>`, so you can use that to draw the lines and add the labels. A couple of loops lets you automate this.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
inner sep=0pt,
anchor=south west,
row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
nodes={draw=black!30,
        anchor=center,
        minimum size=1.1cm,
        outer sep=0pt,
     }
]{
   -t & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1-t & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1-t & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 0 & 1-t & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & -t-1 \\
   };

% for a single row/column
%\node [draw,circle,minimum size=9mm] (a) at (m-1-1.center) {};
%\draw [thick] ([xshift=-1mm]m-1-5.east) -- (a) -- ([yshift=1mm]m-5-1.south);

% or use a loop to do all three at once
\foreach \i in {1,...,3}
{
\node [draw,circle,minimum size=9mm] (a) at (m-\i-\i.center) {};
\draw [thick] ([xshift=-1mm]m-\i-5.east) -- (a) -- ([yshift=1mm]m-5-\i.south);
}

\foreach \i in {1,...,5}
{
\node [above] at (m-1-\i.north) {\i};
\node [left] at (m-\i-1.west) {\i};
}
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```